# twitter bootstrap datepicker internationalization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this [twitter bootstrap style datepicker from Stefan Petre](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker)

However, I don' t know how to set the format of the datepicker to french, apart from changing it directly from the sources, is there a better way to do it ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using a [modified](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) version of Stefan Petre's datepicker, and at the [bottom of the docs](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#i18n) there it says to include your locale file after you included the main datpicker file.

Comment: Hi John, I haven' t got the same link, the one that you provided completed the doc with localizations, thanks alot

Answer (score 8):

dtjmsy, you can use this as well:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: "pt-BR"
});
```

And here a link with a good sandbox where you can try some configurations:
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox

Answer (score 3):

Just add bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js in your code.
and

> $('.datepicker').datepicker({    language: "fr-FR" });

That's it

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.x, you have to internationalizate the moment.js

[Check the source here](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=6J48qV3uQb15hkyHvGWae7RzJ34&cid=TomyYseviyc&s=&fp=538208&mp&projSelected=true#L0)

As follow...

```
// moment.js language configuration
// language : brazilian portuguese (pt-br)
// author : Caio Ribeiro Pereira : https://github.com/caio-ribeiro-pereira

(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['moment'], factory); // AMD
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('../moment')); // Node
    } else {
        factory(window.moment); // Browser global
    }
}(function (moment) {
    return moment.locale('pt-br', {
        months : "janeiro_fevereiro_março_abril_maio_junho_julho_agosto_setembro_outubro_novembro_dezembro".split("_"),
        monthsShort : "jan_fev_mar_abr_mai_jun_jul_ago_set_out_nov_dez".split("_"),
        weekdays : "domingo_segunda-feira_terça-feira_quarta-feira_quinta-feira_sexta-feira_sábado".split("_"),
        weekdaysShort : "dom_seg_ter_qua_qui_sex_sáb".split("_"),
        weekdaysMin : "dom_2ª_3ª_4ª_5ª_6ª_sáb".split("_"),
        longDateFormat : {
            LT : "HH:mm",
            L : "DD/MM/YYYY",
            LL : "D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY",
            LLL : "D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [às] LT",
            LLLL : "dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [às] LT"
        },
        calendar : {
            sameDay: '[Hoje às] LT',
            nextDay: '[Amanhã às] LT',
            nextWeek: 'dddd [às] LT',
            lastDay: '[Ontem às] LT',
            lastWeek: function () {
                return (this.day() === 0 || this.day() === 6) ?
                    '[Último] dddd [às] LT' : // Saturday + Sunday
                    '[Última] dddd [às] LT'; // Monday - Friday
            },
            sameElse: 'L'
        },
        relativeTime : {
            future : "em %s",
            past : "%s atrás",
            s : "segundos",
            m : "um minuto",
            mm : "%d minutos",
            h : "uma hora",
            hh : "%d horas",
            d : "um dia",
            dd : "%d dias",
            M : "um mês",
            MM : "%d meses",
            y : "um ano",
            yy : "%d anos"
        },
        ordinal : '%dº'
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the localized text from the server you could add this (calling it (eg) "somename"):

```
jQuery.fn.datepicker.dates.somename = {
    days: ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"],
    daysShort: ["Вск", "Пнд", "Втр", "Срд", "Чтв", "Птн", "Суб"],
    daysMin: ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"],
    months: ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
    monthsShort: ["Янв", "Фев", "Мар", "Апр", "Май", "Июн", "Июл", "Авг", "Сен", "Окт", "Ноя", "Дек"],
    today: "Сегодня",
    clear: "Очистить",
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    weekStart: 1
};
```

above the calling function (giving the language parameter the value "somename"):

```
jQuery('#datepicker-container input').datepicker({
    language: "somename"
});
```

You can then specify whatever values and language you like from, say, a resx file.