# How to set bootstrap datetimepicher to bulgarian language

Tags: datetimepicker

I want to make calendar in bulgarian language. I tried with:

```html
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/datetimepicker.js"></script>        
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/js/add-datetimeInputs.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3982/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-bg.js"></script>
```

In my  assets/js/add-datetimeInputs.js file I have:

```html
 $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "bg" ] );
$(function () {
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

But it's not in bulgarian language. How should I do that?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340982/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-internalization

Comment: Form where I can see Bulgarian language? - $('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: "pt-BR"
});  But for bulgarian language?